# Get the last word after / in url python

Tags: python, substring

I like simplify my code for get the last word after /

any suggestion?

```
def downloadRepo(repo):
  pos1=repo[::-1].index("/")
  salida=repo[::-1][:pos1]
  print(salida[::-1])

downloadRepo("https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and negative indexing:

```
"https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof".rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
# 'arpspoof'
```

You can also stick with indexes and use [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.rfind):

```
s = "https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof"
index = s.rfind('/')
s[index+1:]
# 'arpspoof'
```

The latter is more memory efficient, since the `split` methods build in-memory lists which contain all the split tokens, including the spurious ones from the front that we don't use.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
string = "https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof"
last_part = string.split("/")[-1]
print(last_part)
```

Which yields

```
arpspoof
```

---

Timing `rsplit()` vs `split()` yields (on my Macbook Air) the following results:

```
import timeit

def schwobaseggl():
    return "https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof".rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

def jan():
    return "https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/arpspoof".split("/")[-1]

print(timeit.timeit(schwobaseggl, number=10**6))
print(timeit.timeit(jan, number=10**6))

# 0.347005844116
# 0.379151821136
```

So the `rsplit` alternative is indeed slightly faster (running it a 1.000.000 times that is).